# Kafka producer acknowledgement time delay and debugging

Tags: apache-kafka

When Kafka producer invokes send() method it returns a future of RecordMetadata which contains

```
 public RecordMetadata(TopicPartition topicPartition,
          long baseOffset,
          long relativeOffset,
          long timestamp,
          java.lang.Long checksum,
          int serializedKeySize,
          int serializedValueSize)
```

This contains the timestamp of the record in the topic/partition but is there a way to find out timestamp of acknowledgment sent by the broker.

I am noticing a delay in acknowledgment receipt and would like to debug further to understand the cause of this delay.
Is there a log level in Kafka broker that allows printing acknowledgment information in server logs?

Comment: You may use an interceptor to monitor and track a message and understand what is happening. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-42%3A+Add+Producer+and+Consumer+Interceptors

Answer (score 0):

I found TRACE log level in both Apache Kafka and Spring Kafka. Could it be what you are looking for.

```
org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate
protected ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> doSend(final ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord) {
    final Producer<K, V> producer = getTheProducer();
    if (this.logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        this.logger.trace("Sending: " + producerRecord);
    }
    ...
producer.send(producerRecord, new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
        ...
        if (KafkaTemplate.this.logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                        KafkaTemplate.this.logger.trace("Sent ok: " + producerRecord + ", metadata: " + metadata);
                    }
        ...
        }
    }
    ...
}

org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
private Future<RecordMetadata> doSend(ProducerRecord<K, V> record, Callback 
callback) {
    ...
    log.trace("Sending record {} with callback {} to topic {} partition {}", 
    record, callback, record.topic(), partition);
    ...
}
```